# Mouseover is acting weird

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a submenu appears only when the mouse is over the parent `<li>` element using jQuery.

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="item">Item 1
       <ul class="sub">
           <li>Sub 1</li>
           <li>Sub 2</li>
       </ul>
  </li>
    <li class="item">Item 1
       <ul class="sub">
          <li>Sub 1</li>
          <li>Sub 2</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li ul{
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

The jquery:

```
$(".item").mouseover(function() {
    var originalHeight = $(this).find(".sub").height();
    $(this).find(".sub").css('height', '0');
    $(this).find(".sub").css('display', 'block');
    $(this).find(".sub").animate({
        height: originalHeight
    }, 1000, function() {});
});

$(".item").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find(".sub").animate({
        height: '0'
    }, 1000, function() {});
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).find(".sub").css('display', 'none');
        $(this).find(".sub").css('height', originalHeight);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gtq9q5gL/

Problem is: the whole thing is acting weird, and i don't know why. Sometimes the submenu appears again even when the mouse is out.

Comment: Try it without the animation delay / with setTimeout set to 1.  If that fixes it, it's because a second event is firing before the first has completed

Comment: "acting weird" is not really a description a programmer should be using, especially not to other programmers. It sounds like a report a user would give to the helpdesk when they are totally clueless. Describe the problematic behaviour accurately and precisely, with examples if appropriate.